# How to Place a Pause in a Windows Phone 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I would like to place a pause within a click event in my application. I am placing a vibration within the click event, and sometimes when a new page is navigated to, the vibration does not stop. I'm hoping that the pause will help solve this issue.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button vibration
    if (Settings.EnableVibration.Value)
    {
        VibrateController.Default.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(40));
        //place vibration stop here
    }        
    ...     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `VibrationController.Default.Stop();`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://andreahaubner.blog.com/2012/01/25/the-vibratecontroller-class/) article, the minimal duration is 0.1 seconds, while you are setting it to 0.04. Also I would try to call the [`VibrateController.Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller.stop%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.